# vue.js 3 .value.click is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

```html
    <template>
            <RecyclablesPopup ref="LVP" class="inline-block m-5px"></RecyclablesPopup>
    </template>

    <script setup>
    import RecyclablesPopup from "../components/popups/RecyclablesPopup";
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    const LVP = ref(null);

    // ... after mounted I have an event with a legacy component and onclick handler:
    eventClick: function(calEvent)
        {
            console.log(LVP.value);
            LVP.value.click();
        }
    </script>
```

At the end I get `Uncaught TypeError: LVP.value.click is not a function` after I clicked.

`console.log` returns me the proxy object as expected `Proxy { <target>: Proxy, <handler>: {…} }`

Why can't I call `click()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `click` function should be exposed by the child component in order be accessed by the parent component :

**RecyclablesPopup component**

```html
<script setup>

function click(){
  //.......
}
defineExpose({
 click
})
</script>
```

for more details please check https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component

Comment: Thanks. defineExpose did the trick! I thought I could call the normal html element click function, but somehow that does not work.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **script setup** you can't access functions, variables, etc., defined inside the referenced component. To change that you have to use the *defineExpose* compiler macro inside *RecyclablesPopup* component - check more in [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose)

```html
//inside RecyclablesPopup
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const click = () => {
    //do something
}

defineExpose({
    click,
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the function on the `onMounted` lifecycle to guarantee that the component is mounted to the DOM, as the value before the component is mounted will be undefined.

```
onMounted(() => {
  eventClick()
})
```

For more resources

https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html#onmounted

Comment: Same problem with `onMounted(() => { LVP.value.click();  });`